# ISNULL of second Left Outer Join value in where statement provides different

Tags: sql, left-join, isnull

In SQL Server when I am attempting to put data into a variable but have a ISNULL around the second left outer join value in the where statement instead of providing the expected result it only returns the last "row" of data.  In the example below you can see in much more detail what I mean.

The first output will show you the generic output, 6 rows of data.  The second output will show you that I am only getting the last row of data in @VAR.  The third output will show you that if I remove ISNULL from FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME in the Order by statement I get all 6 of rows concatenated together (which is what I would think I would also get for the second output).

I want to understand why the second output is returning what it is.  What am I missing?

Really I just want to know why @VAR is different than @VAR2.  The real life example for this is that I was building an HTML table (which is why I was concatenating in this method) and I wanted to order by something more like COALESCE(FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.name, FRUIT_COLOR_YELLOW.NAME, '').  That didn't return the number of rows that I was expecting thus I tried to trace the issue and its something about when there is a ISNULL in the order by statement for the second Left Outer Join.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('FRUIT') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE FRUIT;
GO

CREATE TABLE FRUIT (
name VARCHAR(25),
color INT
);
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('FRUIT_COLOR') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE FRUIT_COLOR;
GO

CREATE TABLE FRUIT_COLOR
(
id INT,
name VARCHAR(25)
);
GO


INSERT into FRUIT_COLOR VALUES (1,'orange');
INSERT into FRUIT_COLOR VALUES(2,'yellow');
INSERT into FRUIT_COLOR VALUES (3,'red');
INSERT into FRUIT_COLOR VALUES (4,'blue');
GO

INSERT into FRUIT VALUES ('banana',2);
INSERT into FRUIT VALUES ('mango',2);
INSERT into FRUIT VALUES ('orange',1);
INSERT into FRUIT VALUES ('apple',3);
INSERT into FRUIT VALUES ('grapes',null);
INSERT into FRUIT VALUES ('avocado',null);
GO

--Test Control - 6 rows of data
SELECT ISNULL(FRUIT.NAME,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.NAME, 'NOT ORANGE ') +  ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME, 'NOT YELLOW ')
FROM FRUIT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUIT_COLOR FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE ON FRUIT.COLOR = FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.ID
        AND FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.NAME = 'Orange'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUIT_COLOR FRUIT_COLOR_yellow ON FRUIT.COLOR = FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.ID
        AND FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME = 'yellow'              
ORDER BY FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.name    
    ,ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME, 'test')


DECLARE @VAR varchar(MAX)
SET @VAR = ''   

--When I attempt to put this to a variable it only shows the last row of data
SELECT @VAR = ISNULL(@VAR, '') + ISNULL(FRUIT.NAME,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.NAME, 'NOT ORANGE ') +  ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME, 'NOT YELLOW ')
FROM FRUIT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUIT_COLOR FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE ON FRUIT.COLOR = FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.ID
        AND FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.NAME = 'Orange'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUIT_COLOR FRUIT_COLOR_yellow ON FRUIT.COLOR = FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.ID
        AND FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME = 'yellow'              
ORDER BY FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.name    
    ,ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME, 'test')    

SELECT @VAR 

DECLARE @VAR2 varchar(MAX)
SET @VAR2 = ''  
--If I remove the ISNULL from FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME in the order by clause I get all 6 results concatonated as I would expect
SELECT @VAR2 = ISNULL(@VAR2, '') + ISNULL(FRUIT.NAME,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.NAME, 'NOT ORANGE ') +  ISNULL(FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME, 'NOT YELLOW ')
FROM FRUIT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUIT_COLOR FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE ON FRUIT.COLOR = FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.ID
        AND FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.NAME = 'Orange'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUIT_COLOR FRUIT_COLOR_yellow ON FRUIT.COLOR = FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.ID
        AND FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME = 'yellow'              
ORDER BY FRUIT_COLOR_ORANGE.name    
    ,FRUIT_COLOR_yellow.NAME    

SELECT @VAR2
```

Comment: +1 . . . I don't think this is a good or safe way to concatenate strings.  BUT . . . I don't see why changing the `order by` condition would have this affect.  Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c03b6/2.

Comment: ummm... so what is the goal?  what do you want it to be sorted by?  both `isnull` for yellow and orange or just the yellow...? I can think of alternative ways to write this so that it definitely would work but I'm really curious as to why it doesn't...

Comment: actually, could you just show me an example of the dataset you want to end up with?

Comment: I just want to know why the end result (I don't care about order) is different for VAR vs. VAR2.  Why would putting ISNULL around a value in the where clause change the output and not just the order?

Comment: the execution plans are different...  annnd there's our answer

Comment: When you rely on undocumented behaviour you can't complain about the result. This approach to string concatenation is documented not to always be reliable via many " won't fix" items on the connect site. Use xml path for consistent results.